# Limiting number of simultaneous connections to certain host on windows

Tags: windows, firewall

I have an application which doing TCP connections to some host, accidentally it could be configured to make a lot of connections to that host and overload it. Is there Windows firewall application which is able reject new connections attempts to specific host when number of allowed connections exceeds?

PS. I have two machines with this application running under Windows 2008 and 2012 server.

Answer (score 1):

No version of the Windows Firewall has functionality to limit connections based on count.

Edit:

I suppose you could use `netstat` with the `-o` argument to show the process IDs of the socket owners and kill the processes. That seems like a bit of a blunt way to do it and you're not actually stopping the TCP SYN from being sent but that's certainly possible.

Comment: may be there console commands which able to show a list of opened connections and kill certain process? It would be enough to create a script which will just kill client application.